# "should be studying" or "should have been studying" when the opportunity is lost by 50%?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, modal-verbs, modality

Ok, for a lost opportunity, we use "**should have + PP**"

Ex: *You have just missed the train because you woke up late. You **should have gone** to bed early yesterday.*

But **What about when the opportunity has lost by 50%?**

Ok, see this situation,

Student A has an English class from 7 AM to 9 AM today. Now is 8 AM & Student A has just woke up. His opportunity is lost by 50%. His father should say:

Option 1: *You should be studying English.*

or

Option 2: *You should have been studying English.*

**Which option is suitable in this context?**

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 seems more suitable in this context but I think none of these options perfectly fit for the father's reply.

Answer (score 1):

Both options are fine, in general discourse.
In the first, *you should be*, the father is allowing the son to understand he should be in class,now.
The second, *you should have been*, has the father allowing the son to understand he needed to be in class before now.
Neither, of course, express a half lost opportunity. They both express lost opportunity. The second option  could be understood as a  completely lost opportunity in another context.
There could be several ways to express the half lost opportunity. Perhaps:

> You should be starting the second half of your English Class now.

I do not think one should attempt to quantify by use of tense. The best one can usually expect from grammatical tense is to express a relative or general time.